# How to encrypt String using Camellia 128-bit Encryption Algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, block-cipher, 128-bit, camellia

Im currently trying to develop a chat application that implement Camellia 128-bit as its encryption algorithm. I succesfully build and run the code from it official page [here][1]. The problem is the algorithm encrypt for Integer datatype. When im trying to encrypt String message, i converted it into ASCII form, but it gives me

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10410110810811132119111114108100"
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
> at Camellia.main(Camellia.java:54)

. I know that it happens because the ASCII code is too long. But im really stuck, and clueless how can i use the algorithm for String encryption. Below is my main code

```
 int[] key = {987777, 1, 2, 3}; // 128 bit key example
 int[] keyTable = new int[52];
 Camellia n=new Camellia();
 n.Camellia_Ekeygen(key, keyTable);

 String c = "";
 String str = "hello world";
 System.out.println(str);
 BigInteger bigInt;
 byte[] bytes;
     try{
        bytes = str.getBytes("US-ASCII");

        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            System.out.print(bytes[i]+",");
            c += String.valueOf(bytes[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        bigInt = new BigInteger(c);
        System.out.println(bigInt);
 }catch(Exception e){};

 int C = Integer.parseInt(c);

 int[] plaintext = {C, 5, 6, 7}; // 128 bit plaintext block example
 int[] ciphertext = new int[4];
 n.Camellia_EncryptBlock(plaintext, keyTable, ciphertext);
 n.Camellia_DecryptBlock(ciphertext, keyTable, plaintext);
```

and here is my full code:-

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Camellia{
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] key = {987777, 1, 2, 3}; // 128 bit key example
    int[] keyTable = new int[52];
 Camellia n=new Camellia();
 n.Camellia_Ekeygen(key, keyTable);

 String c = "";
 String str = "hello world";
 System.out.println(str);
 BigInteger bigInt;
 byte[] bytes;
     try{
        bytes = str.getBytes("US-ASCII");

        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            System.out.print(bytes[i]+",");
            c += String.valueOf(bytes[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        bigInt = new BigInteger(c);
        System.out.println(bigInt);
 }catch(Exception e){};

 int C = Integer.parseInt(c);

 int[] plaintext = {C, 5, 6, 7}; // 128 bit plaintext block example
 int[] ciphertext = new int[4];
 n.Camellia_EncryptBlock(plaintext, keyTable, ciphertext);
 n.Camellia_DecryptBlock(ciphertext, keyTable, plaintext);
 }

    /*
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * S-box data
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
 private final int SBOX1_1110[] =
  {
    0x70707000, 0x82828200, 0x2c2c2c00, 0xececec00, 0xb3b3b300, 0x27272700,
    0xc0c0c000, 0xe5e5e500, 0xe4e4e400, 0x85858500, 0x57575700, 0x35353500,
    0xeaeaea00, 0x0c0c0c00, 0xaeaeae00, 0x41414100, 0x23232300, 0xefefef00,
    0x6b6b6b00, 0x93939300, 0x45454500, 0x19191900, 0xa5a5a500, 0x21212100,
    0xededed00, 0x0e0e0e00, 0x4f4f4f00, 0x4e4e4e00, 0x1d1d1d00, 0x65656500,
    0x92929200, 0xbdbdbd00, 0x86868600, 0xb8b8b800, 0xafafaf00, 0x8f8f8f00,
    0x7c7c7c00, 0xebebeb00, 0x1f1f1f00, 0xcecece00, 0x3e3e3e00, 0x30303000,
    0xdcdcdc00, 0x5f5f5f00, 0x5e5e5e00, 0xc5c5c500, 0x0b0b0b00, 0x1a1a1a00,
    0xa6a6a600, 0xe1e1e100, 0x39393900, 0xcacaca00, 0xd5d5d500, 0x47474700,
    0x5d5d5d00, 0x3d3d3d00, 0xd9d9d900, 0x01010100, 0x5a5a5a00, 0xd6d6d600,
    0x51515100, 0x56565600, 0x6c6c6c00, 0x4d4d4d00, 0x8b8b8b00, 0x0d0d0d00,
    0x9a9a9a00, 0x66666600, 0xfbfbfb00, 0xcccccc00, 0xb0b0b000, 0x2d2d2d00,
    0x74747400, 0x12121200, 0x2b2b2b00, 0x20202000, 0xf0f0f000, 0xb1b1b100,
    0x84848400, 0x99999900, 0xdfdfdf00, 0x4c4c4c00, 0xcbcbcb00, 0xc2c2c200,
    0x34343400, 0x7e7e7e00, 0x76767600, 0x05050500, 0x6d6d6d00, 0xb7b7b700,
    0xa9a9a900, 0x31313100, 0xd1d1d100, 0x17171700, 0x04040400, 0xd7d7d700,
    0x14141400, 0x58585800, 0x3a3a3a00, 0x61616100, 0xdedede00, 0x1b1b1b00,
    0x11111100, 0x1c1c1c00, 0x32323200, 0x0f0f0f00, 0x9c9c9c00, 0x16161600,
    0x53535300, 0x18181800, 0xf2f2f200, 0x22222200, 0xfefefe00, 0x44444400,
    0xcfcfcf00, 0xb2b2b200, 0xc3c3c300, 0xb5b5b500, 0x7a7a7a00, 0x91919100,
    0x24242400, 0x08080800, 0xe8e8e800, 0xa8a8a800, 0x60606000, 0xfcfcfc00,
    0x69696900, 0x50505000, 0xaaaaaa00, 0xd0d0d000, 0xa0a0a000, 0x7d7d7d00,
    0xa1a1a100, 0x89898900, 0x62626200, 0x97979700, 0x54545400, 0x5b5b5b00,
    0x1e1e1e00, 0x95959500, 0xe0e0e000, 0xffffff00, 0x64646400, 0xd2d2d200,
    0x10101000, 0xc4c4c400, 0x00000000, 0x48484800, 0xa3a3a300, 0xf7f7f700,
    0x75757500, 0xdbdbdb00, 0x8a8a8a00, 0x03030300, 0xe6e6e600, 0xdadada00,
    0x09090900, 0x3f3f3f00, 0xdddddd00, 0x94949400, 0x87878700, 0x5c5c5c00,
    0x83838300, 0x02020200, 0xcdcdcd00, 0x4a4a4a00, 0x90909000, 0x33333300,
    0x73737300, 0x67676700, 0xf6f6f600, 0xf3f3f300, 0x9d9d9d00, 0x7f7f7f00,
    0xbfbfbf00, 0xe2e2e200, 0x52525200, 0x9b9b9b00, 0xd8d8d800, 0x26262600,
    0xc8c8c800, 0x37373700, 0xc6c6c600, 0x3b3b3b00, 0x81818100, 0x96969600,
    0x6f6f6f00, 0x4b4b4b00, 0x13131300, 0xbebebe00, 0x63636300, 0x2e2e2e00,
    0xe9e9e900, 0x79797900, 0xa7a7a700, 0x8c8c8c00, 0x9f9f9f00, 0x6e6e6e00,
    0xbcbcbc00, 0x8e8e8e00, 0x29292900, 0xf5f5f500, 0xf9f9f900, 0xb6b6b600,
    0x2f2f2f00, 0xfdfdfd00, 0xb4b4b400, 0x59595900, 0x78787800, 0x98989800,
    0x06060600, 0x6a6a6a00, 0xe7e7e700, 0x46464600, 0x71717100, 0xbababa00,
    0xd4d4d400, 0x25252500, 0xababab00, 0x42424200, 0x88888800, 0xa2a2a200,
    0x8d8d8d00, 0xfafafa00, 0x72727200, 0x07070700, 0xb9b9b900, 0x55555500,
    0xf8f8f800, 0xeeeeee00, 0xacacac00, 0x0a0a0a00, 0x36363600, 0x49494900,
    0x2a2a2a00, 0x68686800, 0x3c3c3c00, 0x38383800, 0xf1f1f100, 0xa4a4a400,
    0x40404000, 0x28282800, 0xd3d3d300, 0x7b7b7b00, 0xbbbbbb00, 0xc9c9c900,
    0x43434300, 0xc1c1c100, 0x15151500, 0xe3e3e300, 0xadadad00, 0xf4f4f400,
    0x77777700, 0xc7c7c700, 0x80808000, 0x9e9e9e00
  };

  private int SBOX4_4404[] =
  {
    0x70700070, 0x2c2c002c, 0xb3b300b3, 0xc0c000c0, 0xe4e400e4, 0x57570057,
    0xeaea00ea, 0xaeae00ae, 0x23230023, 0x6b6b006b, 0x45450045, 0xa5a500a5,
    0xeded00ed, 0x4f4f004f, 0x1d1d001d, 0x92920092, 0x86860086, 0xafaf00af,
    0x7c7c007c, 0x1f1f001f, 0x3e3e003e, 0xdcdc00dc, 0x5e5e005e, 0x0b0b000b,
    0xa6a600a6, 0x39390039, 0xd5d500d5, 0x5d5d005d, 0xd9d900d9, 0x5a5a005a,
    0x51510051, 0x6c6c006c, 0x8b8b008b, 0x9a9a009a, 0xfbfb00fb, 0xb0b000b0,
    0x74740074, 0x2b2b002b, 0xf0f000f0, 0x84840084, 0xdfdf00df, 0xcbcb00cb,
    0x34340034, 0x76760076, 0x6d6d006d, 0xa9a900a9, 0xd1d100d1, 0x04040004,
    0x14140014, 0x3a3a003a, 0xdede00de, 0x11110011, 0x32320032, 0x9c9c009c,
    0x53530053, 0xf2f200f2, 0xfefe00fe, 0xcfcf00cf, 0xc3c300c3, 0x7a7a007a,
    0x24240024, 0xe8e800e8, 0x60600060, 0x69690069, 0xaaaa00aa, 0xa0a000a0,
    0xa1a100a1, 0x62620062, 0x54540054, 0x1e1e001e, 0xe0e000e0, 0x64640064,
    0x10100010, 0x00000000, 0xa3a300a3, 0x75750075, 0x8a8a008a, 0xe6e600e6,
    0x09090009, 0xdddd00dd, 0x87870087, 0x83830083, 0xcdcd00cd, 0x90900090,
    0x73730073, 0xf6f600f6, 0x9d9d009d, 0xbfbf00bf, 0x52520052, 0xd8d800d8,
    0xc8c800c8, 0xc6c600c6, 0x81810081, 0x6f6f006f, 0x13130013, 0x63630063,
    0xe9e900e9, 0xa7a700a7, 0x9f9f009f, 0xbcbc00bc, 0x29290029, 0xf9f900f9,
    0x2f2f002f, 0xb4b400b4, 0x78780078, 0x06060006, 0xe7e700e7, 0x71710071,
    0xd4d400d4, 0xabab00ab, 0x88880088, 0x8d8d008d, 0x72720072, 0xb9b900b9,
    0xf8f800f8, 0xacac00ac, 0x36360036, 0x2a2a002a, 0x3c3c003c, 0xf1f100f1,
    0x40400040, 0xd3d300d3, 0xbbbb00bb, 0x43430043, 0x15150015, 0xadad00ad,
    0x77770077, 0x80800080, 0x82820082, 0xecec00ec, 0x27270027, 0xe5e500e5,
    0x85850085, 0x35350035, 0x0c0c000c, 0x41410041, 0xefef00ef, 0x93930093,
    0x19190019, 0x21210021, 0x0e0e000e, 0x4e4e004e, 0x65650065, 0xbdbd00bd,
    0xb8b800b8, 0x8f8f008f, 0xebeb00eb, 0xcece00ce, 0x30300030, 0x5f5f005f,
    0xc5c500c5, 0x1a1a001a, 0xe1e100e1, 0xcaca00ca, 0x47470047, 0x3d3d003d,
    0x01010001, 0xd6d600d6, 0x56560056, 0x4d4d004d, 0x0d0d000d, 0x66660066,
    0xcccc00cc, 0x2d2d002d, 0x12120012, 0x20200020, 0xb1b100b1, 0x99990099,
    0x4c4c004c, 0xc2c200c2, 0x7e7e007e, 0x05050005, 0xb7b700b7, 0x31310031,
    0x17170017, 0xd7d700d7, 0x58580058, 0x61610061, 0x1b1b001b, 0x1c1c001c,
    0x0f0f000f, 0x16160016, 0x18180018, 0x22220022, 0x44440044, 0xb2b200b2,
    0xb5b500b5, 0x91910091, 0x08080008, 0xa8a800a8, 0xfcfc00fc, 0x50500050,
    0xd0d000d0, 0x7d7d007d, 0x89890089, 0x97970097, 0x5b5b005b, 0x95950095,
    0xffff00ff, 0xd2d200d2, 0xc4c400c4, 0x48480048, 0xf7f700f7, 0xdbdb00db,
    0x03030003, 0xdada00da, 0x3f3f003f, 0x94940094, 0x5c5c005c, 0x02020002,
    0x4a4a004a, 0x33330033, 0x67670067, 0xf3f300f3, 0x7f7f007f, 0xe2e200e2,
    0x9b9b009b, 0x26260026, 0x37370037, 0x3b3b003b, 0x96960096, 0x4b4b004b,
    0xbebe00be, 0x2e2e002e, 0x79790079, 0x8c8c008c, 0x6e6e006e, 0x8e8e008e,
    0xf5f500f5, 0xb6b600b6, 0xfdfd00fd, 0x59590059, 0x98980098, 0x6a6a006a,
    0x46460046, 0xbaba00ba, 0x25250025, 0x42420042, 0xa2a200a2, 0xfafa00fa,
    0x07070007, 0x55550055, 0xeeee00ee, 0x0a0a000a, 0x49490049, 0x68680068,
    0x38380038, 0xa4a400a4, 0x28280028, 0x7b7b007b, 0xc9c900c9, 0xc1c100c1,
    0xe3e300e3, 0xf4f400f4, 0xc7c700c7, 0x9e9e009e
  };

  private final int SBOX2_0222[] =
  {
    0x00e0e0e0, 0x00050505, 0x00585858, 0x00d9d9d9, 0x00676767, 0x004e4e4e,
    0x00818181, 0x00cbcbcb, 0x00c9c9c9, 0x000b0b0b, 0x00aeaeae, 0x006a6a6a,
    0x00d5d5d5, 0x00181818, 0x005d5d5d, 0x00828282, 0x00464646, 0x00dfdfdf,
    0x00d6d6d6, 0x00272727, 0x008a8a8a, 0x00323232, 0x004b4b4b, 0x00424242,
    0x00dbdbdb, 0x001c1c1c, 0x009e9e9e, 0x009c9c9c, 0x003a3a3a, 0x00cacaca,
    0x00252525, 0x007b7b7b, 0x000d0d0d, 0x00717171, 0x005f5f5f, 0x001f1f1f,
    0x00f8f8f8, 0x00d7d7d7, 0x003e3e3e, 0x009d9d9d, 0x007c7c7c, 0x00606060,
    0x00b9b9b9, 0x00bebebe, 0x00bcbcbc, 0x008b8b8b, 0x00161616, 0x00343434,
    0x004d4d4d, 0x00c3c3c3, 0x00727272, 0x00959595, 0x00ababab, 0x008e8e8e,
    0x00bababa, 0x007a7a7a, 0x00b3b3b3, 0x00020202, 0x00b4b4b4, 0x00adadad,
    0x00a2a2a2, 0x00acacac, 0x00d8d8d8, 0x009a9a9a, 0x00171717, 0x001a1a1a,
    0x00353535, 0x00cccccc, 0x00f7f7f7, 0x00999999, 0x00616161, 0x005a5a5a,
    0x00e8e8e8, 0x00242424, 0x00565656, 0x00404040, 0x00e1e1e1, 0x00636363,
    0x00090909, 0x00333333, 0x00bfbfbf, 0x00989898, 0x00979797, 0x00858585,
    0x00686868, 0x00fcfcfc, 0x00ececec, 0x000a0a0a, 0x00dadada, 0x006f6f6f,
    0x00535353, 0x00626262, 0x00a3a3a3, 0x002e2e2e, 0x00080808, 0x00afafaf,
    0x00282828, 0x00b0b0b0, 0x00747474, 0x00c2c2c2, 0x00bdbdbd, 0x00363636,
    0x00222222, 0x00383838, 0x00646464, 0x001e1e1e, 0x00393939, 0x002c2c2c,
    0x00a6a6a6, 0x00303030, 0x00e5e5e5, 0x00444444, 0x00fdfdfd, 0x00888888,
    0x009f9f9f, 0x00656565, 0x00878787, 0x006b6b6b, 0x00f4f4f4, 0x00232323,
    0x00484848, 0x00101010, 0x00d1d1d1, 0x00515151, 0x00c0c0c0, 0x00f9f9f9,
    0x00d2d2d2, 0x00a0a0a0, 0x00555555, 0x00a1a1a1, 0x00414141, 0x00fafafa,
    0x00434343, 0x00131313, 0x00c4c4c4, 0x002f2f2f, 0x00a8a8a8, 0x00b6b6b6,
    0x003c3c3c, 0x002b2b2b, 0x00c1c1c1, 0x00ffffff, 0x00c8c8c8, 0x00a5a5a5,
    0x00202020, 0x00898989, 0x00000000, 0x00909090, 0x00474747, 0x00efefef,
    0x00eaeaea, 0x00b7b7b7, 0x00151515, 0x00060606, 0x00cdcdcd, 0x00b5b5b5,
    0x00121212, 0x007e7e7e, 0x00bbbbbb, 0x00292929, 0x000f0f0f, 0x00b8b8b8,
    0x00070707, 0x00040404, 0x009b9b9b, 0x00949494, 0x00212121, 0x00666666,
    0x00e6e6e6, 0x00cecece, 0x00ededed, 0x00e7e7e7, 0x003b3b3b, 0x00fefefe,
    0x007f7f7f, 0x00c5c5c5, 0x00a4a4a4, 0x00373737, 0x00b1b1b1, 0x004c4c4c,
    0x00919191, 0x006e6e6e, 0x008d8d8d, 0x00767676, 0x00030303, 0x002d2d2d,
    0x00dedede, 0x00969696, 0x00262626, 0x007d7d7d, 0x00c6c6c6, 0x005c5c5c,
    0x00d3d3d3, 0x00f2f2f2, 0x004f4f4f, 0x00191919, 0x003f3f3f, 0x00dcdcdc,
    0x00797979, 0x001d1d1d, 0x00525252, 0x00ebebeb, 0x00f3f3f3, 0x006d6d6d,
    0x005e5e5e, 0x00fbfbfb, 0x00696969, 0x00b2b2b2, 0x00f0f0f0, 0x00313131,
    0x000c0c0c, 0x00d4d4d4, 0x00cfcfcf, 0x008c8c8c, 0x00e2e2e2, 0x00757575,
    0x00a9a9a9, 0x004a4a4a, 0x00575757, 0x00848484, 0x00111111, 0x00454545,
    0x001b1b1b, 0x00f5f5f5, 0x00e4e4e4, 0x000e0e0e, 0x00737373, 0x00aaaaaa,
    0x00f1f1f1, 0x00dddddd, 0x00595959, 0x00141414, 0x006c6c6c, 0x00929292,
    0x00545454, 0x00d0d0d0, 0x00787878, 0x00707070, 0x00e3e3e3, 0x00494949,
    0x00808080, 0x00505050, 0x00a7a7a7, 0x00f6f6f6, 0x00777777, 0x00939393,
    0x00868686, 0x00838383, 0x002a2a2a, 0x00c7c7c7, 0x005b5b5b, 0x00e9e9e9,
    0x00eeeeee, 0x008f8f8f, 0x00010101, 0x003d3d3d
  };

  private final int SBOX3_3033[] =
  {
    0x38003838, 0x41004141, 0x16001616, 0x76007676, 0xd900d9d9, 0x93009393,
    0x60006060, 0xf200f2f2, 0x72007272, 0xc200c2c2, 0xab00abab, 0x9a009a9a,
    0x75007575, 0x06000606, 0x57005757, 0xa000a0a0, 0x91009191, 0xf700f7f7,
    0xb500b5b5, 0xc900c9c9, 0xa200a2a2, 0x8c008c8c, 0xd200d2d2, 0x90009090,
    0xf600f6f6, 0x07000707, 0xa700a7a7, 0x27002727, 0x8e008e8e, 0xb200b2b2,
    0x49004949, 0xde00dede, 0x43004343, 0x5c005c5c, 0xd700d7d7, 0xc700c7c7,
    0x3e003e3e, 0xf500f5f5, 0x8f008f8f, 0x67006767, 0x1f001f1f, 0x18001818,
    0x6e006e6e, 0xaf00afaf, 0x2f002f2f, 0xe200e2e2, 0x85008585, 0x0d000d0d,
    0x53005353, 0xf000f0f0, 0x9c009c9c, 0x65006565, 0xea00eaea, 0xa300a3a3,
    0xae00aeae, 0x9e009e9e, 0xec00ecec, 0x80008080, 0x2d002d2d, 0x6b006b6b,
    0xa800a8a8, 0x2b002b2b, 0x36003636, 0xa600a6a6, 0xc500c5c5, 0x86008686,
    0x4d004d4d, 0x33003333, 0xfd00fdfd, 0x66006666, 0x58005858, 0x96009696,
    0x3a003a3a, 0x09000909, 0x95009595, 0x10001010, 0x78007878, 0xd800d8d8,
    0x42004242, 0xcc00cccc, 0xef00efef, 0x26002626, 0xe500e5e5, 0x61006161,
    0x1a001a1a, 0x3f003f3f, 0x3b003b3b, 0x82008282, 0xb600b6b6, 0xdb00dbdb,
    0xd400d4d4, 0x98009898, 0xe800e8e8, 0x8b008b8b, 0x02000202, 0xeb00ebeb,
    0x0a000a0a, 0x2c002c2c, 0x1d001d1d, 0xb000b0b0, 0x6f006f6f, 0x8d008d8d,
    0x88008888, 0x0e000e0e, 0x19001919, 0x87008787, 0x4e004e4e, 0x0b000b0b,
    0xa900a9a9, 0x0c000c0c, 0x79007979, 0x11001111, 0x7f007f7f, 0x22002222,
    0xe700e7e7, 0x59005959, 0xe100e1e1, 0xda00dada, 0x3d003d3d, 0xc800c8c8,
    0x12001212, 0x04000404, 0x74007474, 0x54005454, 0x30003030, 0x7e007e7e,
    0xb400b4b4, 0x28002828, 0x55005555, 0x68006868, 0x50005050, 0xbe00bebe,
    0xd000d0d0, 0xc400c4c4, 0x31003131, 0xcb00cbcb, 0x2a002a2a, 0xad00adad,
    0x0f000f0f, 0xca00caca, 0x70007070, 0xff00ffff, 0x32003232, 0x69006969,
    0x08000808, 0x62006262, 0x00000000, 0x24002424, 0xd100d1d1, 0xfb00fbfb,
    0xba00baba, 0xed00eded, 0x45004545, 0x81008181, 0x73007373, 0x6d006d6d,
    0x84008484, 0x9f009f9f, 0xee00eeee, 0x4a004a4a, 0xc300c3c3, 0x2e002e2e,
    0xc100c1c1, 0x01000101, 0xe600e6e6, 0x25002525, 0x48004848, 0x99009999,
    0xb900b9b9, 0xb300b3b3, 0x7b007b7b, 0xf900f9f9, 0xce00cece, 0xbf00bfbf,
    0xdf00dfdf, 0x71007171, 0x29002929, 0xcd00cdcd, 0x6c006c6c, 0x13001313,
    0x64006464, 0x9b009b9b, 0x63006363, 0x9d009d9d, 0xc000c0c0, 0x4b004b4b,
    0xb700b7b7, 0xa500a5a5, 0x89008989, 0x5f005f5f, 0xb100b1b1, 0x17001717,
    0xf400f4f4, 0xbc00bcbc, 0xd300d3d3, 0x46004646, 0xcf00cfcf, 0x37003737,
    0x5e005e5e, 0x47004747, 0x94009494, 0xfa00fafa, 0xfc00fcfc, 0x5b005b5b,
    0x97009797, 0xfe00fefe, 0x5a005a5a, 0xac00acac, 0x3c003c3c, 0x4c004c4c,
    0x03000303, 0x35003535, 0xf300f3f3, 0x23002323, 0xb800b8b8, 0x5d005d5d,
    0x6a006a6a, 0x92009292, 0xd500d5d5, 0x21002121, 0x44004444, 0x51005151,
    0xc600c6c6, 0x7d007d7d, 0x39003939, 0x83008383, 0xdc00dcdc, 0xaa00aaaa,
    0x7c007c7c, 0x77007777, 0x56005656, 0x05000505, 0x1b001b1b, 0xa400a4a4,
    0x15001515, 0x34003434, 0x1e001e1e, 0x1c001c1c, 0xf800f8f8, 0x52005252,
    0x20002020, 0x14001414, 0xe900e9e9, 0xbd00bdbd, 0xdd00dddd, 0xe400e4e4,
    0xa100a1a1, 0xe000e0e0, 0x8a008a8a, 0xf100f1f1, 0xd600d6d6, 0x7a007a7a,
    0xbb00bbbb, 0xe300e3e3, 0x40004040, 0x4f004f4f
  };



 private int ct0,ct1,ct2,ct3;
 private int pt0,pt1,pt2,pt3;

 private int RightRotate(int x, int s){
    return (((x) >>> (s)) + ((x) << (32 - s)));
 };

 private long LeftRotate(int x, int s){
    return ((x) << (s)) + ((x) >>> (32 - s)) ;
 };


 /*
  *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * Computes the exclusive-or of x and y and and assigns it to z, ie,
  *
  * z = x ^ y
  *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */
  private void XorBlock(int[] x , int x_ ,int[] y, int y_, int[] z, int z_){
     z[0 + z_] = x[0 + x_] ^ y[0 + y_];
     z[1 + z_] = x[1 + x_] ^ y[1 + y_];
     z[2 + z_] = x[2 + x_] ^ y[2 + y_];
     z[3 + z_] = x[3 + x_] ^ y[3 + y_];
  };
  /*
   *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * This function is only used in key generation.
   *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

   private static void RotBlock
   (
      int x[], int x_,
      int n,
      int y[], int y_
   )
   {
      int r = (n & 31);   /* Must not be 0 */
      int idx = (n >>> 5);
      int idx1 = (idx + 1) & 3;
      int idx2 = (idx1 + 1) & 3;

      y[0 + y_] = (x[idx + x_] << r) | (x[idx1 + x_] >>> (32 - r));
      y[1 + y_] = (x[idx1 + x_] << r) | (x[idx2 + x_] >>> (32 - r));
  }




  /* Key generation constants */

  private final int SIGMA1[] = {
  0xa09e667f, 0x3bcc908b,
  0xb67ae858, 0x4caa73b2};
  private final int SIGMA2[] = {
  0xc6ef372f, 0xe94f82be,
  0x54ff53a5, 0xf1d36f1c};

  /*
   * As for this variable, it is used in 192/256 bit version camellia.
   */
   private final int SIGMA3[] = {
   0x10e527fa, 0xde682d1d,
   0xb05688c2, 0xb3e6c1fd};


  private int KSFT1[] = {
      0, 64, 0, 64, 15, 79, 15, 79, 30, 94, 45, 109, 45, 124, 60, 124, 77, 13,
      94, 30, 94, 30, 111, 47, 111, 47
  };

  private int KIDX1[] = {
     0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 8, 8
  };

 /*
  * As for this variable, it is used in 192/256 bit version camellia.
  */
  private int KSFT2[] = {
     0, 64, 0, 64, 15, 79, 15, 79, 30, 94, 30, 94, 45, 109, 45, 109, 60, 124,
     60, 124, 60, 124, 77, 13, 77, 13, 94, 30, 94, 30, 111, 47, 111, 47
  };

 /*
  * As for this variable, it is used in 192/256 bit version camellia.
  */
  private int KIDX2[] = {
     0, 0, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 12, 12, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 4, 4, 12, 12,
     0, 0, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 8, 0, 0, 12, 12
  };

  private void Camellia_Feistel
  (
      int[] x, int x_,
      int[] k, int k_,
      int key_offset
  )
  {
int D, U;
int s1, s2;

s1 = x[0 + x_] ^ k[0 + k_];

U  = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
s2 = x[1 + x_] ^ k[1 + k_];
D  = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

x[2 + x_] ^= D ^ U ;
x[3 + x_] ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8);

s1 = x[2 + x_] ^ k[key_offset + k_];
U = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
s2 = x[3 + x_] ^ k[key_offset+1 + k_];
D = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

x[0 + x_] ^= D ^ U  ;
x[1 + x_] ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8) ;

}

 /*
  * Optimized F Function
  */
  private void Camellia_Feistel_Enc
  (
     int[] k, int k_
  )
  {
     int D, U;
     int s1, s2;

     s1 = ct0 ^ k[0 + k_];

     U  = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
     U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
     U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
     U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
     s2 = ct1  ^ k[1 + k_];
     D  = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
     D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
     D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
     D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

     ct2 ^= D ^ U ;
     ct3 ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8);

     s1 = ct2  ^ k[2 + k_];
     U = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
     U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
     U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
     U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
     s2 = ct3 ^ k[3 + k_];
     D = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
     D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
     D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
     D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

    ct0 ^= D ^ U  ;
    ct1 ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8) ;

  }

  private void Camellia_Feistel_Dec(int[] k, int k_)
 {
    int D, U;
    int s1, s2;

    s1 = pt0 ^ k[0 + k_];

U  = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
s2 = pt1  ^ k[1 + k_];
D  = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

pt2 ^= D ^ U ;
pt3 ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8);

s1 = pt2  ^ k[k_ - 2];
U = SBOX4_4404[s1 & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX3_3033[(s1 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX2_0222[(s1 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
U ^= SBOX1_1110[(s1 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];
s2 = pt3 ^ k[k_ - 1];
D = SBOX1_1110[s2 & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX4_4404[(s2 >>> 8 ) & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX3_3033[(s2 >>> 16) & 0x000000FF];
D ^= SBOX2_0222[(s2 >>> 24) & 0x000000FF];

pt0 ^= D ^ U  ;
pt1 ^= D ^ U ^ RightRotate(U, 8) ;
}

public void Camellia_Ekeygen(int[] rawKey,int[] keyTable){
int t[] = new int[16];
int  i;

memcpy(t, 0, rawKey, 0, 4);
 for (i = 4; i < 8; i++) t[i] = 0;


XorBlock(t, 0, t , 4, t, 8);
Camellia_Feistel(t, 8, SIGMA1, 0, 2);
XorBlock(t, 8, t, 0, t, 8);
Camellia_Feistel(t, 8, SIGMA2, 0, 2);
memcpy(keyTable, 0, t, 0, 16);
memcpy(keyTable, 4, t, 8, 8);

    for (i = 4; i < 26; i += 2 ){
        RotBlock(t , KIDX1[i + 0], KSFT1[i + 0], keyTable, i*2);
        RotBlock(t , KIDX1[i + 1], KSFT1[i + 1], keyTable, i*2+2);
    }
 }

public void Camellia_EncryptBlock(int plaintext[],int keyTable[],int ciphertext[]){
   int j;
   int grandRounds;

   int k = 4;

   ct0 = keyTable[0] ^ (plaintext[0]);
   ct1 = keyTable[1] ^ (plaintext[1]);
   ct2 = keyTable[2] ^ (plaintext[2]);
   ct3 = keyTable[3] ^ (plaintext[3]);

   for (grandRounds = 0; grandRounds < 3; grandRounds++)
   {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j+=2, k += 4)
            Camellia_Feistel_Enc(keyTable,k);

     if (grandRounds < 2)
     {
        ct1 ^= LeftRotate(ct0 & keyTable[k + 0], 1);
        ct0 ^= ct1 | keyTable[k + 1];
        ct2 ^= ct3 | keyTable[k + 3];
        ct3 ^= LeftRotate(ct2 & keyTable[k + 2], 1);
        k += 4;
     }
   }

ciphertext[0] = keyTable[k + 0] ^ (ct2);
ciphertext[1] = keyTable[k + 1] ^ (ct3);
ciphertext[2] = keyTable[k + 2] ^ (ct0);
ciphertext[3] = keyTable[k + 3] ^ (ct1); System.out.println(String.valueOf(ciphertext[0])+","+String.valueOf(ciphertext[1])+","+String.valueOf(ciphertext[2])+","+String.valueOf(ciphertext[3]));

}

public void Camellia_DecryptBlock
(
int ciphertext[],
int keyTable[],
int plaintext[]
)
 {
  int grandRounds;
  int j;
  int k;

k = 48;

pt0 = keyTable[k + 0] ^ (ciphertext[0]);
pt1 = keyTable[k + 1] ^ (ciphertext[1]);
pt2 = keyTable[k + 2] ^ (ciphertext[2]);
pt3 = keyTable[k + 3] ^ (ciphertext[3]);

k -= 2;

for (grandRounds = 0; grandRounds < 3; grandRounds++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j+=2, k -= 4)
        Camellia_Feistel_Dec(keyTable,k);

    if (grandRounds < 2)
    {
        pt1 ^= LeftRotate(pt0 & keyTable[k + 0], 1);
        pt0 ^= pt1 | keyTable[k + 1];
        pt2 ^= pt3 | keyTable[k - 1];
        pt3 ^= LeftRotate(pt2 & keyTable[k - 2], 1);
        k -= 4;
    }
}

k -= 2;

plaintext[0] = keyTable[k + 0] ^ (pt2);
plaintext[1] = keyTable[k + 1] ^ (pt3);
plaintext[2] = keyTable[k + 2] ^ (pt0);
plaintext[3] = keyTable[k + 3] ^ (pt1);

int C = plaintext[0];
//char c =(char) C;
String c = String.valueOf(C);
asciiToSentence(c,c.length());

System.out.println(c+","+String.valueOf(plaintext[1])+","+String.valueOf(plaintext[2])+","+String.valueOf(plaintext[3]));

   }

 private static final void memcpy(int[] dst , int dst_ ,int[] src, int src_ ,int leng)
 {
    for(int i=0; i < leng ;i++){
        dst[i + dst_]=src[i + src_];
    }
 }

static void asciiToSentence(String str, int len)
{
    String st = "";
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        // Append the current digit
        num = num * 10 + (str.charAt(i) - '0');

        // If num is within the required range
        if (num >= 32 && num <= 122) {

            // Convert num to char
            char ch = (char)num;
            System.out.println(ch);
            // Reset num to 0
            num = 0;
        }
    }
}


};
```

```
  [1]: https://info.isl.ntt.co.jp/crypt/eng/camellia/dl/camellia-java-BSD-1.0.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Do you want to study the algorithm or just apply it? For the latter it's easier to use e.g. [BouncyCastle, see 6.2 Algorithms](https://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html).

Comment: @Topaco i want to apply it. But actually i want to apply it into Flutter. ive tried using Bouncy Castle, it works perfect with Java. but when im brought it into Flutter, it give me BC provider does not support the padding. fyi, i did a connection with Java and Dart, so thats why ill able to run the code in Flutter. But it gives me the error which i dont get while compiling it with Java tools editor

Comment: @Topaco Update: I'm able to encrypt using AES provider, but i want to use Camellia but it says the provider isnt available. I believe that the problem is at `Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); ` ive tried changing it to `Camellia/CBC/PKCS7Padding` but it says no such provider found

Comment: In this post you asked for an implementation in Java. If you are now looking for an implementation in Dart, you should ask a new question in which you post your most recent Dart code and describe the problem.  If necessary, you can refer to this question. Thanks.

Comment: @Topaco, sorry my bad. i actually wanted to study the algorithm without using any library like bouncy castle. can u guide me how to encrypt a string using camellia?

Comment: If you want to study the algorithm itself, you could look at the specification, e.g. [RFC 3713, A Description of the Camellia Encryption Algorithm](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3713). Another approach is to analyze an existing (reliable) implementation, e.g. BouncyCastle, whose sources can be downloaded, see [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html), section _Sources and JavaDoc_, e.g. _bcprov-jdk15on-167\src\org\bouncycastle\crypto\engines\CamelliaEngine.java_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented by @Topaco it's a lot of work to check the implementation for an encryption algorithm "just for fun" so below you find a working example of a full encryption/decryption program that uses the Bouncy Castle security provider.

The program is running with an 128 bit = 16 byte long key and uses the **CBC-mode** - it could be "downgraded" to use the ECB-mode but this is not recommended as the **ECB-mode is unsecure and should be no longer used for a new application**.

It encrypts a string to a byte array and back to the original string:

```
Camellia 128 CBC encryption with Bouncy Castle
plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
plaintext  length: 43 data: 54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a756d7073206f76657220746865206c617a7920646f67
ciphertext length: 48 data: 56629f6df124b289c18da9baa80efd3bc12833c69916d2dea1bc58bad250f5a6f78bb440c086308426e1eb10e9d952bc
decry.text length: 43 data: 54686520717569636b2062726f776e20666f78206a756d7073206f76657220746865206c617a7920646f67
decryptedtext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**Security warning: the program has no exception handling and is for educational purpose only.**

code:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;

public class MainSo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        System.out.println("Camellia 128 CBC encryption with Bouncy Castle");

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        String plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        byte[] plaintextBytes = plaintext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        // generate random key + iv
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] key = new byte[16]; // 16 bytes = 128 bit key
        secureRandom.nextBytes(key);
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
        // setup cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Camellia/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        // encryption
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintextBytes);
        System.out.println("plaintext: " + plaintext);
        System.out.println("plaintext  length: " + plaintextBytes.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(plaintextBytes));
        System.out.println("ciphertext length: " + ciphertext.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(ciphertext));
        // decryption
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] decryptedtext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
        System.out.println("decry.text length: " + decryptedtext.length + " data: " + bytesToHex(decryptedtext));
        System.out.println("decryptedtext: " + new String(decryptedtext));
    }
    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: actually im trying to study the algorithm. Im not allowed to use any library like bouncy castle. can u guide me at least to encrypt a string using the camellia algorithm?

Comment: @random peeps: I'm sorry I has never to do with Camellia algo - try to find a native library, comapre the results with BC results and adopt the algo to your needs.